# Javascript - setInterval, animation, delay

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I know I can use **animation** and **@keyframes** in CSS but I want to have this problem solved below. I want to pause this animation later using **clearInterval** (<- but thats not my question).

What the problem is, this animation starts after one second. What can I do to make animation working immediately after refreshing the page? **[(- JSFIDDLE -)](http://jsfiddle.net/kardaw/ej7c3/)**

```
<div id="myID"></div>
-----------------------
var i = 0;
var thesquare = document.getElementById('myID');
function FunRotate()
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
        thesquare.style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)';
        i++;
        break;

        default:
        thesquare.style.transform = 'rotate(-20deg)';
        i=0;
        break;
    }
}
setInterval(FunRotate, 1000);
```

**EDIT**: No it isn't a duplicate. I want to have the first step of animation immediately.

Comment: Your Edit comment, that is what the dupe answer does....

Answer (score 0):

Add `FunRotate();` once before your `setInterval(FunRotate, 1000);` ...

Answer (score 0):

Invoke it immediately and set a `timeOut` for the next one at the end of the call:

```
function FunRotate()
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case 0:
    thesquare.style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)';
    i++;
    break;

    default:
    thesquare.style.transform = 'rotate(-20deg)';
    i=0;
    break;

    setTimeout(FunRotate, 1000);
}

FunRotate();
```